# Можно ли подключать модуль авторизации allauth в django на локальном сервере?

Tags: django

Ребята имеется проект на django на локальном сервере, установлено приложение библиотека allauth и по ссылке работает, хочу сделать авторизацию через вк или инстаграм. 
Можно ли это сделать на локалке, о есть авторизацию на локальном сервере или как его настроить уже в продакшене?

Comment: Можно, по крайней мере раньше я вк подключал.

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от используемых вами социальных приложений. Например, вы можете указать в качестве обратного адреса 127.0.0.1 в настройках приложения ВКонтакте.

Прочитайте официальную документацию тех социальных приложений, которые вы собираетесь использовать